# Can't compare types

Tags: vb.net

I want to see if try cast can convert user entered answer to the type I have specified.

Here's what I have:

```
Dim t as type = GetType(myType)
Dim ans = console.readline()

If TryCast(ans, t) <> Nothing Then ... 'Doesn't work`
```

In the example above the intelisense doesn't even show t. How to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to check if the user's input is string, int, bool, date etc...

So if you want to convert the `readline()` to a specific type, you can do the following:

```
If myType.GetType Is GetType(Integer) Then
    'your code...
ElseIf myType.GetType Is GetType(DateTime) Then
   ....
```

Dennis reply is also a good idea ..

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the type. If `ans` which is of type `string` can be cast to `myType` then the following should work. Of course, without knowing the implementation of `myType` I can't tell if the casting will work.

```
Dim ans = console.readline()
If TryCast(ans, myType) <> Nothing Then
    ...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've got other issues there with your myType, but you test for Nothing by using Is:

```
If myObject Is Nothing Then
```

or

```
If myObject IsNot Nothing Then
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to see if try cast can convert user entered answer to the type
>   I have specified.

In this case, you don't want to `Cast`, you want to `Parse` the user's answer. Let's say a user enters a value as a String, and you want to parse it to an Integer, you would do:

```
Dim userInput As String = "123"
Dim intValue As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(userInput, intValue) Then
    'User's answer is an int
End If
```